# Python Elasticsearch - Look in multiple fields for exact match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have two fields `field_1` and `field_2`. I have a to find exact match for my query in either `field_1` or `field_2`. `multi_match` is not giving me exact matches. And `constant_score` does not support `multi_match`.

The elasticsearch version I'm using:

`Version: 6.3.0, Build: default/rpm/424e937/2018-06-11T23:38:03.357887Z, JVM: 1.8.0_171`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of reading the docs and trying different queries this worked for me:

```
query = {
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [
                 { "term" : {"field_1" : "<search query>"}},
                 { "term" : {"field_2" : "<search query>"}}
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```